# Envoy Task Runner: run command that requires sudo access

Tags: laravel-5, ssh, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-envoy

I am using https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/envoy as a deployment tool.
In the Envoy.blade.php, I have command that requires sudo access for example:-

```
chmod 777 -R storage/
chmod 777 -R bootstrap/cache
```

These commands fails with an error saying operation not permitted. How can we resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

I changed the following configuration on the server

```
sudo visudo
```

and add

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

All commands can now be executed without entering a password

You can also specify individual commands

```
username ALL=(username) NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 4):

To run those commands as sudo try the following:

```
echo "{{ $password }}" | sudo -S chmod 777 -R storage/
echo "{{ $password }}" | sudo -S chmod 777 -R bootstrap/cache
```

Obviously you'll need to pass the sudo password into the envoy run command.

```
envoy run mytask --password=mypass
```

Tested on Ubuntu server 16.04 & 17.04